# .net core console app solution do not have project entry while creating new project in visual studio profession 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, console-application

When i am creating .net core console app in visual studio profession 2019, its not showing any project  under current solution. Images are enclosed for references. Please suggest.
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/528434/vs2019-solution-trees-are-empty.html . . . have a look at this

Comment: @WaleedNaveed: i already check this link but it was not helpful. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstall all the older .Net Core Sdk (i.e .Net Core Sdk 1.1.xx and .Net Core Sdk 2.2.xx) from my machine. After this i have only Microsoft .Net Core Sdk 3.1.101 install on my machine which installed at the time of vs 2019 installation.

Now i am able to see the project under current solution.